How to make remove a token that uses my name?
is my case: let's assume that someone deployed a token with the exact name of my website with also the exact .extension, is there a way to make it remove?

No, you can't delete things from the blockchain this way. The only way to overcome scammers imitating your company is to create awareness among your community/users.
